# A Printer that has multiple MAC Addresses?

Tags: network-printer, mac-address, network-interface

I have a Lexmark printer that for some reason shows multiple MAC addresses when its connected to a switch.

Thats so weird. Anybody had the same problem?

How can I solve it and how come it has multiple MAC addresses??

It has to be a mistake... it has only one network interface...

Comment: does it have wireless?

Comment: What problem is that causing you?

Comment: More then a single device connected to the switch?

Comment: How about a model number of your printer? Does it have Bluetooth?

Comment: Where do you see the multiple addresses? On the printer's config page, on the DHCP server, somewhere else?

Comment: Does each MAC receives one IP address? The same, or different? Does each IP address respond to pings?

Comment: Are both MAC address the same OUI (the first half)?